# Can't get track ID3 tags using jaudiotagger

Tags: java, android, jaudiotagger

I'm trying to read ID3 tags from a `.m4a` file using the jaudiotagger Library with the following code

```
try {
        File file = new File(TrackPath);
        AudioFile f = AudioFileIO.read(file);
        Tag tag = f.getTag();

        audioAlbum.setText(tag.getFirst(FieldKey.ARTIST));
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    };
```

But this returns the same error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method toPath()Ljava/nio/file/Path; in class Ljava/io/File;
```

The string TrackPath contains the "MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA" of the `.m4a` file

I have never worked with exceptions before, so I think the problem is somewhere in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, the original Library is not working for Android due to some java versions problems. So ended up using this library instead https://github.com/hexise/jaudiotagger-android

Comment: can you help me do the same?
I downloaded the files and used Eclipse to export it to a jar, but when I added that to android dependencies of my app, I am still getting the same 
NoSuchMethodFind error .
I'll be truly grateful. 
Could you provide me with directions/instructions ?

Answer (score 1):

I just remplaced this :

```
Tag tag = audioFile.getTag();
```

By this :

```
Tag tag = audioFile.getTagAndConvertOrCreateAndSetDefault();
```

I use jaudiotagger2.2.7

To install it just add this in your buil project :

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}
```

and this to your build module app (dependencies) :

```
implementation 'com.github.goxr3plus:jaudiotagger:2.2.7'
```